# Passing Object as parameter in Object Datasource

Tags: asp.net

I have an object datasource and that objectdatasource has an update method the method has an update parameter.. mY question is how can I pass the object to the object datasource as a parameter.? Any Idea

Comment: Any code samples to help?

Comment: What do you mean by "the object"?  Which object?  The object being provided by the `ObjectDataSource`?

Comment: the parameter in that object datasource is an object 'Class'